# Retrieve Index Number of Unique Elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

```
for (let i = 0; i < arrayItemsLen; i++) {
  let uniqueItems = arrayItems.filter(function(item, i, arrayItems) {
    return i == arrayItems.indexOf(item);
  });
}
```

This method retrieves unique items in the `arrayItems` to `uniqueItems` array. What I want to do is also get the index numbers of each unique element and assign it to another temp array. I can't find a way to achieve that.

E.g.: `arrayItems.indexOf(item)` gives the index of each unique element, but then, how do I get that index to the `tempArray[i]`, I guess I need a for loop but I really don't know where to put it.

Comment: `arrayItems.map(function(item, i, arrayItems) {
  return arrayItems.indexOf(item);
});`

Comment: Why do you need the for loop? Note you are recreating `uniqueItems` at each iteration.

Comment: @Oriol to iterate through unique items, get their index and assign it to tempArray. Maybe there is a way without for loop but I don't know.

Comment: @dandavis That kinda works, it gives the indexes of unique items, but I get repeated indexes like: [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6], is it me or is it your code?

Comment: you can tack the map onto the end of the filter and delete the third formal parameter to use closure-provided access to the unfiltered array, thus returning the positions of uniques in the orig.

Comment: @Oriol Oh wow, thank you for warning me about recreating uniqueItems at each iteration... that was useless ugh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like

```
var uniqueIndices = [],
    uniqueValues = [];
for(var i=0; i<array.length; ++i) {
    if(uniqueValues.indexOf(array[i]) >= 0) continue;
    uniqueIndices.push(i);
    uniqueValues.push(array[i]);
}
```

Basically, it iterates `array` checking if the current value is already in `uniqueValues`. If it's there, it does nothing and continues to the next iteration. Otherwise, it adds the value to `uniqueValues` and the key to `uniqueIndices`.

Using `i == array.indexOf(array[i])` like in your question would also work, but it may be slower because `array` will be bigger than `uniqueValues`.

Comment: Would you please explain your code a bit? It works as I wanted but I can't understand how it works, and this ~ confuses me most.

Comment: I have added an explanation and removed `~` for clarity.